# CodeIgniter huge session store in database table does it make slow performance?

Tags: codeigniter-2

I will develop a system with using huge session by CodeIgniter, i worry it may make my system slow because with huge session CodeIgniter recommend to store in table, that mean every time i perform `this->session->userdata('mysession_name')` it will query to database server.
So the more i perform `this->session->userdata('mysession_name')` the more queries access to database server. I imagine if 100 users login so how may query to database server?

Comment: Anyone can share idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building your database schema it is all about how you index the data, if you have a good structure your query will be executed extremely fast and have little effect on performance overall. Don't dump everything in one table, just place the items important to what you wish to do with session data, break it down into sections if possible. Having 2 queries that can build up a user object or array as opposed to one slow query is a good tradeoff.